# Gradle Multi module annotationProcessor compilation issue between Room Database And Glide Plugins

Tags: android, android-room, android-glide, android-database

below is my build.gradle file dependencies

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    implementation('com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"


}
```

I am using two plugin annotationProcessor  one for Room database and other for Glide Plugin but as soon as i add annotationProcessor for Room Database. It seem GLide annotationProcessor is getting override and I am getting compilation error for Glide Plugin in my project. How to run both in my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your root gradle look like this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
 }
```

Comment: Can you please clean the build and make project?